# Генератор списка списков python

Tags: python, list, матрицы

У меня есть код который генерирует список списков

```
n =  [[(i/j) for j in range (1,5)] for i in range (1,5)]
```

Вывод

```
[[1.0, 0,5, 0.33333333333, 0,25],
[2.0, 1.0, 0.66666666666, 0.5],
[3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75],
[4.0, 2.0, 1.33333333333, 1.0]]
```

Вопрос 1) как обратиться к списку списков с помощью генератора
2) как итерировать этот список списков с помощью генератора, чтобы значения лежащие в пределах от 0.5 до 2.5 оставались без изменений, а остальные изменили знак на минус

Comment: С помощью генератора можно сгенерировать новый список, а не поменять старый. Вообще судя по всему вам и надо новый список сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью генератора (list comprehension) вы создали исходный список. А менять с помощью генератора ничего не получится по определению (логично же, да?). Поэтому, делаете еще один `list comprehension`:

```
n =  [[(i/j) for j in range (1,5)] for i in range (1,5)]
```

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25],
 [2.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5],
 [3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75],
 [4.0, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333, 1.0]]
```

```
n = [[x  if (x > 0.5 and x < 2.5) else x*-1 for x in y] for y in n]
```

```
[[1.0, -0.5, -0.3333333333333333, -0.25],
 [2.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, -0.5],
 [-3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75],
 [-4.0, 2.0, 1.3333333333333333, 1.0]]
​
```